# Higher speed options for executing very large (20 GB) .sql file in MySQL

Tags: mysql, large-files, database-restore, navicat, high-speed-computing

My firm was delivered a 20+ GB .sql file in reponse to a request for data from the gov't. I don't have many options for getting the data in a different format, so I need options for how to import it in a reasonable amount of time. I'm running it on a high end server (Win 2008 64bit, MySQL 5.1) using Navicat's batch execution tool. It's been running for 14 hours and shows no signs of being near completion.

Does anyone know of any higher speed options for such a transaction? Or is this what I should expect given the large file size?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I guess you mean it's a file produced by `mysqldump` as a backup of a database, so it contains mostly `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements.

(But strictly speaking, an SQL script can contain anything, such as definition and execution of long-running stored procedures, queries that result in deadlocks, etc.  I'll assume this is *not* the case.)

Here are some things you can do to speed up restore, given that you have the backup file and can't change the type of file it is:

1. Disable foreign key checks: [`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks) (remember to re-enable 
   afterwards).  Disable unique checks too: [`SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_unique_checks)
2. Make sure your [`key_buffer_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_key_buffer_size) is set as large as possible if you use MyISAM tables.  The default is 8MB, and the max is 4GB.  I'd try 1GB.

   These first tips come from a post by Baron Schwartz:  http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/206866
3. Make sure your [`innodb_buffer_pool_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) is set as large as possible if you use InnoDB tables.  The default is 8MB, and the max is 4GB.  I'd try 1GB.
4. Set [`innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit) during the restore if you use InnoDB tables.
5. @Mark B adds a good suggestion below to [disable keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) during a restore.  This is how you do it:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE <table-name> DISABLE KEYS;
   ...run your restore...
   ALTER TABLE <table-name> ENABLE KEYS;
   ```

   But that command affects only one table at a time.  You'll have to issue a separate command for each table.  That said, it's often the case that one table is much larger than the other tables, so you may need to disable keys only for that one large table.

   Also, if the SQL script containing your restore drops and recreates tables, this would circumvent disabling keys.  You'll have to find some way to insert the commands to disable keys after the table is created and before rows are inserted.  You may need to get creative with `sed` to preprocess the SQL script before feeding it to the mysql client.
6. Use the Percona Server version of mysqldump, with the [--innodb-optimize-keys](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/management/innodb_expanded_fast_index_creation.html) option.

Comment: May also want to disable keys on the tables for the duration of the import. That's usually the killer on large imports - the mass updating of keys.

Answer (score 2):

There is a big amount of tools around, but I would recommend Navicat GUI to do that.
In my experience it could run 48GB *.sql files in 6 hours on a host with 8GB of RAM.

Explanation (sort of) here:
[image]
Secondary click on chosen DB, select "Execute SQL File", choose the file, choose "continue on error" if you want to and finally run it.
I know it shows a MySQL DB but works on most used/popular DBMS.

I seriously don't advise to "open" a file of such proportions in their sql query builder, it would block the machine as the RAM would be at full capacity over and over again.

This also works on Macintosh OS as host of Navicat application and once you are connected to a given DB Server you can run it wherever you want, working pretty well on RHEL, Ubuntu Server, Debian and Windows Server until now.

Answer (score 0):

Use BULK Import in MySQL for this.

Answer (score 0):

Request just the table definitions, and the data in a .csv.  Then do a bulk-import.